# Thymeleaf URL Forwarding Problem to External URL in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've created a Spring Boot App, in which I am fetching data from external API, store them in database and then displaying them back at front-end in HTML using Thymeleaf. Everything works perfectly fine except one thing.

One of the columns in db, has the name "Headline" which is mapped as String variable. I am using this variable as hyperlink in my Spring Boot app combined with URLs stored in the same database, to redirect to the source of them. Below I am showing my front-end code.

**Front-End Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:https="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/db.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>


</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
    <li><a th:href="@{https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos}" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Cryptocurrency News</h1>
    </div>

</main>
    <!--Display DB contents on HTML and Thymeleaf-->
    <div class="container text-center" id="tasksDiv">
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>News Provider Name</th>
                    <th>News Link</th>
                    <th>Related Image</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="rate: ${rates}">
                        <td th:text="${rate.news_provider_name}"> </td>
                        <td>
                            <a
                                    th:href="@{${rate.news_link}}"
                                    target="_blank"
                                    th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td> <img th:src="${rate.related_image}" alt="error displaying image"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

When I am running my application everything displays just fine, but as soon as I press the texted hyperlinks, I am redirected at the home page instead of the given URLs which I've stored in my DB. Below, I am showing you my printscreen in which you can definitely see that URLs have been fetched and assigned properly, when I am hovering my cursor above them in my browser, just before I press them. But as soon as they do get pressed, I am getting redirection [here](https://www.investing.com/), instead of
[here](https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626).

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

[image: Browser View]

**UPDATE**

In the above code I changed the `th:href="${rate.news_link}` to `th:href="@{${rate.news_link}}` but still nothing works. If, for example, my initial URL is

```
https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626
```

gets chopped off to `https://www.investing.com/`

[image: Broswer Console]

[image: Broswer Console 2]

Comment: Any redirects configured at webserver layer? Do you see `300*` response codes when you click on `href`? You can check this via browser console.

Comment: @harshavmb I checked. Indeed there are some blocked and cancelled parameters. I updated my question with pictures.